# How to Perform a Between Operator similar to SQL in mapreduce Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to write a mapreduce job which will emulate a between operator of sql query

My scenario is I have 2 hdfs files with me:

HDFS File 1 contains start date, end date and changed Date:

```
Start Date    | End Date   |    Changed Date
dd/MM/yyyy    | dd/MM/yyyy |    dd/MM/yyyy
dd/MM/yyyy    | dd/MM/yyyy |    dd/MM/yyyy
dd/MM/yyyy    | dd/MM/yyyy |    dd/MM/yyyy
... ... ..
```

HDFS File 2 contains Data on which between operator needs to be performed

```
Data 1    |   Data 2     |  DATE data | other data......
Data 1    |   Data 2     |  DATE data | other data......
Data 1    |   Data 2     |  DATE data | other data......
Data 1    |   Data 2     |  DATE data | other data......
...
```

I need to change the "DATE data" of HDFS file 2 with the value of the  "Changed Date" from HDFS file 1

**IF and ONLY IF**

"DATE data" from HDFS file 2 is between the "Start Date" and "End Date" of HDFS file 1

Basically its a Between Operation in the where clause of SQL query

What is the best or appropriate approach to tackle this problem in hadoop.

Should I write HIVE or PIG or use HBASE to tacke this issue?

I discussed with a Hadoop consultant casually where he was Saying that Writing Custom Map Reduce Jobs will be more Flexible and Faster for execution.
More over it also helps in Designing.

**I am basically doing this to perform ETL operations.**

Please suggest the best approach and how can this be done via custom Map reduce
Programming.

Comment: how big is your HDFS File 1 compared to HDFS File 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

If both the tables are structured, you can create them as external tables in Hive and run a simple sql to fetch the required result.
Or a custom lookup mapreduce will also do the job. The custom lookup program would be less expensive